# How to create a new domain-component - openLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

All of the examples and documentation I've been perusing always uses ou=groups. Due to a desire for greater flexibility (such as renaming groups), I would like to make groups (an all other top levels of the DIT) as domain-components instead.

My current base is dc=openldap,dc=example,dc=com

My goal is to end up with DNs like cn=username,dc=admins,dc=openldap,dc=example,dc=com

I have been unable to find documentation or tutorials that use DCs for common objects in place of OUs.

How do I create a new group node as a domain component instead of an organizational unit?

For reference, I'm trying to implement the best practice design described [here](https://www.skills-1st.co.uk/papers/ldap-schema-design-feb-2005/ldap-schema-design-feb-2005.html).

Comment: I am starting to question if I should be using "openlap" in the DN base since it it just one of the services/apps and there are other services using ldap which don't include "openldap" in their FQDNs. Seems my base should just be dc=example,dc=com

Comment: I never include the LDAP directory application's name in the naming context (or, more generally, I don't include the application name in pretty much any naming) as product names change over time and/or applications are replaced. It's cosmetic -- OpenDJ or ApacheDS will serve dc=openldap,dc=mycompany,dc=gTLD just fine -- but then you've got to explain to all of the new people *why* your naming context says OpenLDAP when you've not been using it for six years now :-)

Comment: But a domain component IS NOT an organizational unit. You won't be able to provide any `groupofnames` object in it using a 'fake ou', thus you will also not be able to provision any `member` attribute in these. I think the best practice is to use DC's to reflect the [FQ]DN, or at least a domain related thing, but nothing more.